# How do I use the Serial Console in Azure to connect to VM

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine

1. Created another post where the .pem file has permission issues after working all day it suddenly stopped letting me .ssh in
2. Created 4 VMs with no luck using ssh from my machine to the VM
3. Started connecting via Serial Console (it worked)
4. Messed up on server, stood up 5th box
5. Trying to access via Serial Console
6. Prompted for password
7. Never created password
8. Followed article [resets the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess?tryIt=true&source=docs#reset-password)

Error:

```
(VMExtensionProvisioningError) VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'enablevmaccess'. Error message: "Enable failed: Failed to generate public key file."

More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionlinuxtroubleshoot 
Code: VMExtensionProvisioningError
Message: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'enablevmaccess'. Error message: "Enable failed: Failed to generate public key file."

More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/vmextensionlinuxtroubleshoot
```

My Question Is:

How do I either:

1. Connect to Azure VM locally using ssh
2. Connect via Azure Serial Console in the Portal
   a. Have to first setup a password for the user

Answer (score 1):

Connecting SSH to Azure VM, I followed the below steps:

While creating virtual machine you can make use of username and password and select inbound ports rule as SSH(22) like below:

[image]

To connect SSH in your terminal use ssh username@yourpublicip

```
 ssh username@20.164.215.XXX
```

[image]

***Output***

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1104-azure x86_64)
* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 System information as of Mon Mar 27 06:38:39 UTC 2023
 System load:  0.4               Processes:           112
 Usage of /:   4.5% of 28.89GB   Users logged in:     0
 Memory usage: 5%                IP address for eth0: 10.2.0.4
 Swap usage:   0%
 
Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.
0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

Ensure that in your ***VM -> networking -> inbound port rule SSH 22*** is allow in action like below:

[image]

***I tried to login with serial console, In Vm ->serial console -> Only username and password its login successfully  like below:***

[image]

***Output***

```
  Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS testvm1 ttyS0

testvm1 login: Imran123
Password: 
Last login: Mon Mar 27 06:38:41 UTC 2023 from 49.207.213.83 on pts/0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1104-azure x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon Mar 27 06:45:45 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           107
  Usage of /:   4.6% of 28.89GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 6%                IP address for eth0: 10.2.0.4
  Swap usage:   0%


Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Enable ESM Apps to receive additional future security updates.
See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: sudo pro status

New release '20.04.6 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

Imran123@testvm1:~$ 2023/03/27 06:52:22.661338 INFO Daemon Agent WALinuxAgent-2.9.0.4 launched with command 'python3 -u bin/WALinuxAgent-2.9.0.4-py2.7.egg -run-exthandlers' is successfully running
```

To Reset password in Virtual machine :

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create and use an SSH key pair for Linux VMs in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mac-create-ssh-keys)